# Is it possible to intercept php file paths and substitute with other?

Tags: php, glusterfs

I have two web servers, replicated document root with glusterfs.
Unfortunately, file_exists , is_dir and all functions using system call lstat spoil performance of my site, because they check files' status on both hdd. It takes long time.

The question - is it possible to intercept php file paths and substitute with other?
I'd like to make copy of CMS code outside glusterfs brick.

There is method Phar::interceptFileFuncs, but it works only for phar applications. Maybe, there's analogue for normal php application?